# media query in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, media-queries

Hi all I have following code:
[my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-dream-rtvwt)

As you see I have "mystyle" which have `fontSize: 35px` and `color:"red"`.

```
      const mystyle = {
        fontSize: "35px",
        color: "red"
      };
```

Also I added  **react-responsive** helper to set `World` component visible when `max-width` will equal to **600px**.

```
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: "(max-width: 600px)" });
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={mystyle}> hello </div>
        {isMobile && <World />}
      </div>
   );
```

Now my question is: How can I change `fontSize` to `20px` and `color` to `"blue"` in my "mystyle" when max-width will equal to 600px ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const mystyle = {
        fontSize: "35px",
        color: "red"
};

const mystyle2 = {
        fontSize: "20px",
        color: "blue"
};

<div style={isMobile ? mystyle2 : mystyle}> hello </div>
```